# Efficency for reading file names of a directory ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, performance, directory, webserver

How efficient is reading the names of files in a directory in ASP.NET?

Background: I want to update pictures on a webserver automatically and deploy them in advance. E.g. until the 1. April I want to pick 'image1.png'. After the 1. April 'image2.png'. To achieve this I have to map every image name to a date which indicates if this image has to be picked or not.

In order to avoid mapping between file name and date in a seperate file or database the idea is to put a date in the file name. Iterating the directory and parsing the dates make me find my file.

E.g.:

- image_2013-01-01.png
- image_2013-04-31.png

The second one will be picked from May to eternity if no image with a later date will be dropped.

So I wonder how this solution impacts the speed of a website assuming <20 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using something like `Directory.GetFiles`, that is one call to the OS.
This will access the disk to get the listing.

For less that 20 files this will be very quick. However since this data is unlikely to change very often, consider caching the name of your image.

You could store it in the [application context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.context.aspx) to share it among all users of your site.